# Pass data from a form to a controller in yii2

Tags: yii2

I am creating a page that has 3 fields - product code, startdate, enddate. When I click on the search button it should create a pdf file. 3 of these fields are without model.
[image]

I've tried code -

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
//use yii\grid\GridView;
use kartik\grid\GridView;
use kartik\export\ExportMenu;
use frontend\modules\stock\models\Sellitem;
use dosamigos\datepicker\DatePicker;
use dosamigos\datepicker\DateRangePicker;
use kartik\form\ActiveForm;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $searchModel frontend\modules\stock\models\SellitemSearch */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

$this->title = 'Stock';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="sellitem-index">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
    <?php // echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
                <label for="upc" class="control-label"><p class="text-info">Product Code&nbsp;<i class="icon-star"></i></p></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="upc" class="span3">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
                <label for="upc" class="control-label"><p class="text-info">Start Date&nbsp;<i class="icon-star"></i></p></label>
                <?= DatePicker::widget([
                //'label' => 'Startdate',
                'name' => 'startdate',
                'id' => 'startdate',
                //'value' => '02-16-2012',
                'template' => '{addon}{input}',
                    'clientOptions' => [
                        'autoclose' => true,
                        'todayHighlight' => true,
                        'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd'
                    ]
                ]);?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
                <label for="upc" class="control-label"><p class="text-info">End Date&nbsp;<i class="icon-star"></i></p></label>
                <?= DatePicker::widget([
                //'label' => 'Startdate',
                'name' => 'enddate',
                'id' => 'enddate',
                //'value' => '02-16-2012',
                'template' => '{addon}{input}',
                    'clientOptions' => [
                        'autoclose' => true,
                        'todayHighlight' => true,
                        'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd'
                    ]
                ]);?>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <p>
        <div class="form-group pull-right">
            <?= Html::a('Search', ['/stock/sellitem/stockbetweendates','upc'=> $upc, 'startdate'=> $startdate, 'enddate'=>$enddate], 
        ['class'=>'btn btn-success']) 
        ?>
        </div>
    </p>
</div>
```

This is giving error - undefined variable.
I've added $upc, $startdate, $enddate in the model but it's not helping. Please let me know what to do to pass these values to controller.

Controller Action

```
public function actionStockbetweendates($upc, $startdate, $enddate) {

$upc = yii::$app->request->get('upc');
$startdate = yii::$app->request->get('startdate');
$enddate = yii::$app->request->get('enddate');

// $modelProduction = Puritem::find()->where(['pi_upc' => $productname]);
// $searchModel1  = new PuritemsbSearch();
// $dataProvider1 = $searchModel1->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams, $productname);

// $modelSell  = Sellitem::find()->where(['si_iupc' => $productname]);
// $searchModel2 = new SellitemsbSearch();       
// $dataProvider2 = $searchModel2->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams, $productname);

// $content = $this->renderPartial('_printproductledger', [
//     'modelProduction' => $modelProduction,
//     'dataProvider1' => $dataProvider1,
//     'searchModel1'  => $searchModel1,
//     //'data'=> $data,

//     'modelSell' => $modelSell,
//     'searchModel2' => $searchModel2,          
//     'dataProvider2' => $dataProvider2,

//     'productname' => $productname,
//     'prodesc' => $prodesc,

//     ]);
// $footer = "<table name='footer' width=\"1000\">
//    <tr>             
//      <td style='font-size: 18px; padding-bottom: 20px;' align=\"right\">Signature</td>
//    </tr>
//  </table>";
// $pdf = new Pdf([
//     'mode'=> Pdf::MODE_UTF8,
//     'format'=> Pdf::FORMAT_A4,
//     'destination'=> Pdf::DEST_BROWSER,
//     'orientation'=> Pdf::ORIENT_LANDSCAPE,
//     //'destination' => Pdf::DEST_DOWNLOAD,
//     'cssFile' => '@vendor/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/assets/kv-mpdf-bootstrap.min.css',
//     // any css to be embedded if required
//     'cssInline' => '.kv-heading-1{font-size:18px}', 
//      // set mPDF properties on the fly
//     'options' => ['title' => 'Print Party Ledger'],
//     //'options' => ['defaultfooterline' => 0,],
//     'options' => ['defaultheaderline' => 0,],
//      // call mPDF methods on the fly
//     'methods' => [
//         'SetHeader'=>['Ledger'], 
//         //'SetFooter'=>[$footer],
//     ],
//     'content' => $content,

// ]);
// return $pdf->render();
//return $this->render('_printSalarystatement', ['s_period' => $s_period]);

}
```

ActionIndex that renders to the index2 page

```
public function actionIndex2()
    {
        $searchModel = new SellitemSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index2', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            ]);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Which one is undefined? You need to pass through controller, not model.

Comment: Ok, show me how your method in controller looks like.

Comment: Controller Action and Error screen added in the question.

Comment: Right. Where is your `$upc` value located at? Can you also give me that code that assigns a value to `$upc`?

Comment: I've added public $upc; public $startdate; public $enddate; in model sellitem.

Comment: You also miss name in `<input type="text" class="form-control" id="upc" class="span3">` and you can get post values from form fields via `Yii::$app->request->post()`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how it works without rendering... But anyway, to make them defined, you need to pass them to view file. The most common method (and I think the best by far) is to use `$this->render()` operation. At the end of of your `public function actionStockbetweendates($upc, $startdate, $enddate) {` add this:

```
return $this->render('index2', [
    'upc' => $upc,
    'startdate' => $startdate,
    'enddate' => $enddate,
];
```

One side note: you don't need to use these:

```
$upc = yii::$app->request->get('upc');
$startdate = yii::$app->request->get('startdate');
$enddate = yii::$app->request->get('enddate');
```

They are already defined (used) in parameters.

Comment: The first page to load is stock/sellitem/index2. stock is themodule, sellitem is controller and index2 is the page that contains the 1 textbox and 2 datepickers.In this page itlesf I'm getting undefined index:upc error. as shown.

Comment: My method should solve that issue for you. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes. I have. Same result.

Comment: I've added your code in in the controller action which is rendering to the index2 page and it seems to be working.

Comment: I've added the ActionIndex in the question that is rendering to the page index2. I guess you are asking me to add your code in this Controller action.