# Generate pdf by controller action when data is passed through javascript in yii2

Tags: yii2

This is the continuation of question [Pass data from a form to a controller in yii2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41789534/pass-data-from-a-form-to-a-controller-in-yii2?noredirect=1#comment70769248_41789534) and [Get data from textbox and pass to Controller in yii2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41830205/get-data-from-textbox-and-pass-to-controller-in-yii2/41831014#41831014).

I'm trying to generate a report by controllerAction `actionStockbetweendates`. The parameters for this `productname`, `startdate`, `enddate` comes from `index2` through a javascript function on clicking of a button. In console I'm getting the following error.

[image]

index2.php

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
//use yii\grid\GridView;
use kartik\grid\GridView;
use kartik\export\ExportMenu;
use frontend\modules\stock\models\Sellitem;
use dosamigos\datepicker\DatePicker;
use dosamigos\datepicker\DateRangePicker;
use kartik\form\ActiveForm;
use yii\helpers\Json;
use yii\db\Query;
use yii\db\Command;
use kartik\mpdf\Pdf;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $searchModel frontend\modules\stock\models\SellitemSearch */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

$this->title = 'Stock';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="sellitem-index">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
    <?php // echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
                <label for="upc" class="control-label"><p class="text-info">Product Code&nbsp;<i class="icon-star"></i></p></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="upc" class="span3">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
                <label for="upc" class="control-label"><p class="text-info">Start Date&nbsp;<i class="icon-star"></i></p></label>
                <?= DatePicker::widget([
                //'label' => 'Startdate',
                'name' => 'startdate',
                'id' => 'startdate',
                //'value' => '02-16-2012',
                'template' => '{addon}{input}',
                    'clientOptions' => [
                        'autoclose' => true,
                        'todayHighlight' => true,
                        'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd'
                    ]
                ]);?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
                <label for="upc" class="control-label"><p class="text-info">End Date&nbsp;<i class="icon-star"></i></p></label>
                <?= DatePicker::widget([
                //'label' => 'Startdate',
                'name' => 'enddate',
                'id' => 'enddate',
                //'value' => '02-16-2012',
                'template' => '{addon}{input}',
                    'clientOptions' => [
                        'autoclose' => true,
                        'todayHighlight' => true,
                        'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd'
                    ]
                ]);?>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <p>
        <div class="form-group pull-right">
            <button id="yourButton" class="btn btn-primary" >Seach</button>           
        </div>
    </p>
</div>
<?php
/* start getting the itemid */
$this->registerJs(
      "$('#yourButton').on('click', function() { 
          var productname = $('#upc').val();
          var startdate = $('#startdate').val();
          var enddate = $('#enddate').val();

          //alert(uPc);

          $.get('index.php?r=stock/sellitem/stockbetweendates',{ productname : productname, startdate : startdate,  enddate : enddate}, function(data){

            var data = $.parseJSON(data);


            });
      });"
  );
/* end getting the itemid */
?>
```

ControllerAction

```
public function actionStockbetweendates($productname, $startdate, $enddate) {

        $modelProduction = Puritem::find()->where(['pi_upc' => $productname]);
        $searchModel1  = new PuritemsbSearch();
        $dataProvider1 = $searchModel1->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams, $productname);

        $modelSell  = Sellitem::find()->where(['si_iupc' => $productname]);
        $searchModel2 = new SellitemsbSearch();       
        $dataProvider2 = $searchModel2->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams, $productname);

        $content = $this->renderPartial('_printproductledgerbtdt', [
            'modelProduction' => $modelProduction,
            'dataProvider1' => $dataProvider1,
            'searchModel1'  => $searchModel1,
            //'data'=> $data,

            'modelSell' => $modelSell,
            'searchModel2' => $searchModel2,          
            'dataProvider2' => $dataProvider2,

            'productname' => $productname,
            //'prodesc' => $prodesc,

            ]);
        $footer = "<table name='footer' width=\"1000\">
           <tr>             
             <td style='font-size: 18px; padding-bottom: 20px;' align=\"right\">Signature</td>
           </tr>
         </table>";
        $pdf = new Pdf([
            'mode'=> Pdf::MODE_UTF8,
            'format'=> Pdf::FORMAT_A4,
            'destination'=> Pdf::DEST_BROWSER,
            'orientation'=> Pdf::ORIENT_LANDSCAPE,
            //'destination' => Pdf::DEST_DOWNLOAD,
            'cssFile' => '@vendor/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/assets/kv-mpdf-bootstrap.min.css',
            // any css to be embedded if required
            'cssInline' => '.kv-heading-1{font-size:18px}', 
             // set mPDF properties on the fly
            'options' => ['title' => 'Print Party Ledger'],
            //'options' => ['defaultfooterline' => 0,],
            'options' => ['defaultheaderline' => 0,],
             // call mPDF methods on the fly
            'methods' => [
                'SetHeader'=>['Ledger'], 
                //'SetFooter'=>[$footer],
            ],
            'content' => $content,

        ]);
        return $pdf->render();
        //return $this->render('_printSalarystatement', ['s_period' => $s_period]);
        return $this->render('index2', [
            'upc' => $upc,
            'startdate' => $startdate,
            'enddate' => $enddate,
        ]);

    }
```

updated javascript

```
<?php
/* start getting the itemid */
$this->registerJs(
      "$('#yourButton').on('click', function() { 
          var productname = $('#upc').val();
          var startdate = $('#startdate').val();
          var enddate = $('#enddate').val();

          //alert(uPc);
          $.get('index.php?r=stock/sellitem/stockbetweendates',{ productname : productname, startdate : startdate,  enddate : enddate});

      });"
  );
/* end getting the itemid */
?>
```

Updated Controller Action

```
public function actionStockbetweendates($productname, $startdate, $enddate) {

        $modelProduction = Puritem::find()->where(['pi_upc' => $productname]);
        $searchModel1  = new PuritemsbSearch();
        $dataProvider1 = $searchModel1->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams, $productname);

        $modelSell  = Sellitem::find()->where(['si_iupc' => $productname]);
        $searchModel2 = new SellitemsbSearch();       
        $dataProvider2 = $searchModel2->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams, $productname);

        $content = $this->renderPartial('_printproductledgerbtdt', [
            'modelProduction' => $modelProduction,
            'dataProvider1' => $dataProvider1,
            'searchModel1'  => $searchModel1,
            //'data'=> $data,

            'modelSell' => $modelSell,
            'searchModel2' => $searchModel2,          
            'dataProvider2' => $dataProvider2,

            'productname' => $productname,
            //'prodesc' => $prodesc,

            ]);
        $footer = "<table name='footer' width=\"1000\">
           <tr>             
             <td style='font-size: 18px; padding-bottom: 20px;' align=\"right\">Signature</td>
           </tr>
         </table>";
        $pdf = new Pdf([
            'mode'=> Pdf::MODE_UTF8,
            'format'=> Pdf::FORMAT_A4,
            'destination'=> Pdf::DEST_BROWSER,
            'orientation'=> Pdf::ORIENT_LANDSCAPE,
            //'destination' => Pdf::DEST_DOWNLOAD,
            'cssFile' => '@vendor/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/assets/kv-mpdf-bootstrap.min.css',
            // any css to be embedded if required
            'cssInline' => '.kv-heading-1{font-size:18px}', 
             // set mPDF properties on the fly
            'options' => ['title' => 'Print Party Ledger'],
            //'options' => ['defaultfooterline' => 0,],
            'options' => ['defaultheaderline' => 0,],
             // call mPDF methods on the fly
            'methods' => [
                'SetHeader'=>['Ledger'], 
                //'SetFooter'=>[$footer],
            ],
            'content' => $content,

        ]);
        return $pdf->render();

    }
```

Output
[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Earlier used button to call Controller action and passing parameter

```
[
            'class' => 'kartik\grid\ActionColumn',
            'template' => '{ledger}',
            'buttons' => [
                'ledger' => function ($url, $model) {
                    //var_dump($model);
                    //exit;
                    return Html::a(
                        '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>',
                        ['/stock/sellitem/printproductledger', 'productname' => $model['i_upc'],'prodesc'=>$model['i_desc']],

                        [
                            'title' => 'Ledger',
                            'data-pjax' => '0',
                        ]
                    );
                },
            ],
            ],
```

Updated Controller Action

```
public function actionPrintproductledger2($productname) {

        $productname = yii::$app->request->get('productname');
        $prodesc = yii::$app->request->get('prodesc');

        $modelProduction = Puritem::find()->where(['pi_upc' => $productname]);
        $searchModel1  = new PuritemsbSearch();
        $dataProvider1 = $searchModel1->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams, $productname);

        $modelSell  = Sellitem::find()->where(['si_iupc' => $productname]);
        $searchModel2 = new SellitemsbSearch();       
        $dataProvider2 = $searchModel2->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams, $productname);

        Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;

        return $this->render('_printproductledgerbtdt', [
            'modelProduction' => $modelProduction,
            'modelSell' => $modelSell,
            'dataProvider1' => $dataProvider1,
            'searchModel1'  => $searchModel1,
            'searchModel2' => $searchModel2,          
            'dataProvider2' => $dataProvider2,
            'productname' => $productname,
            'prodesc' => $prodesc,
        ]);
    }
```

updated javascript

```
<?php
/* start getting the itemid */
$this->registerJs(
      "$('#yourButton').on('click', function() { 
          var productname = $('#upc').val();
          var startdate = $('#startdate').val();
          var enddate = $('#enddate').val();
          var desc = $('#desc').val();

          //alert(productname);
          //$.get('index.php?r=stock/sellitem/printproductledger2',{ productname : productname, startdate : startdate,  enddate : enddate,prodesc:desc}); 

            $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'index.php?r=stock/sellitem/printproductledger2',
            data: { productname:productname, startdate : startdate,  enddate : enddate,prodesc:desc},
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            //dataType: 'json',
            success: function() { alert('Success'); }

            });
      });"
  );
/* end getting the itemid */
?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You code can't work for several reason

so this is not properly an answer  but some main suggetions

1) you are using   this call for obtain data

```
 $.get('index.php?r=stock/sellitem/stockbetweendates',
       { productname : productname, startdate : startdate,  enddate : enddate}, 
   function(data){
        var data = $.parseJSON(data);
        });
```

the data obtain are not correctly JSON formatted ..

If you need  correct data JSON format you should encode_JSON properly in you action and send this data to the caller  using an echo.

2 ) In you actionStockbetweendates

you have two time the return statement

```
      ]);
    return $pdf->render();
    //return $this->render('_printSalarystatement', ['s_period' => $s_period]);
    return $this->render('index2', [
        'upc' => $upc,
        'startdate' => $startdate,
        'enddate' => $enddate,
    ]);
```

obviously only the firts work  .. and (could be) render a pdf ..

but in this way yuo are not sending nothings to  the ajax caller  ($.get...)

My suggestion is that you split you code in separated function .. each of this specifically related  to a single need .

And for pdf  try using

```
         'mode' => Pdf::MODE_BLANK,
```

instead of ( `'mode'=> Pdf::MODE_UTF8,`)

Comment: Hi scaiseEdge, I got your point #2... But I've very little knowlege on the json. Can you have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41789534/pass-data-from-a-form-to-a-controller-in-yii2?noredirect=1#comment70769248_41789534.. If I can pass the data without Javascript and json, I can print the pdf myself.

Comment: The use of ajax ($.get..)  is not mandatory  iyou can pass data using a simple yii2 url with param .. as usual ..  or if in ajax you don't need  result you can avoid the function for managing data .. too

Comment: That is what I want too. Please have a look at the link I've given in the previous comment.

Comment: @Tanmay   . i have looked at the link .. but for me that  link  is not usful for your need .. ( the render don't work for returning ajax value .. you should use echo  )  and, i repeat,  if you only need a simple action call  you can use  .. a normal yii2  Url::to(...) ... or the ajax $.get(.....) without the function(data) for manage the response  ..

Comment: Hi scaisEdge, Ive removed the function(data) and updated the present javascript code in the question. Now, I think the controller action is being calle as there's no error in the console. But I don't know how to return the pdf. I'm not getting any output. Please let me know how to display the pdf. Or please tell me how to use yii2 Url::to to call the controller action. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean for return  .. the PDF ?  .. the PDF can be create and view  .. like others PDF render ... .. Once you have called  the Yii2 action.. is the action itesefl that manage the pdf creation and show .. ...but most important  have i suggested you of split the problem  in several simple problem ... you don't ... you are continuning  to change a complex ... an wrong code  (and approach ..) hope this is clear ..

Comment: I understand. But I don't know how to do it. Can you please show me what the code would be like. Thanks.

Comment: I can't provide  the code  because your problem  in not coding problem .. but a conceptual and architectural problem .. you must decide  if you need  ajax (  JSON is a data notation,,  a data format convention) or not .. then you must decide  if you need  a pdf download or a pdf  render ... so  .. i suggest you of study better  ..   your app requirement .. (eventually) the ajax technology .. and what do you need for PDF ..

Comment: I want to display the generated pdf in the browser.

Comment: then  you don't need  the second render   and you can invoke you action passing your vars  .. then you have already coded  PDF using  in past and you can see the related  code for completion..

Comment: I've done that. I've added the updated controller action and the output. I can see the parameters are passing but don't get the pdf in the browser. I'm sure I'm missing something.

Comment: the code seems correct so you must investigate in models collection and render_partial view  code  ..

Comment: I've added 2 screen print of browser console in the question. Please have a look.The model seems ok. I've tested by calling the other working controller action.

Comment: I will be glad to do that... Please show me how to do that.

Comment: are you not able to write the code for a button that invoke an action?  . I can hardly believe it. Do not use the javascript code to the click on the launch button and use the php code to create the destination url in the button .. if you can not in this way, for the last time I suggest you divide your problem into problems simple

Comment: Earlier I called controller action by a button successfully. And called action and passed parameter through action column button also.I've added the working code of it in the question. But in this case, the textboxes are only bootstrap textboxes and I need to get the data from the textbox and pass it as parameter to controller action as well. I didn't do it earlier. Please let me know how to do it.

Comment: Why sir? It's a matter of 2 minutes  to you I know.

Comment: because if you need ajax .. you have already the code .. and then you must chek why your pdf not work ... when to me seem al correct ..

Comment: Can we get the value from the textboxes and pass it as parameters to controller by yii2 code? I mean without ajax? Like I did through the action column button (I've given the code in the question earlier)?

Comment: I think the problem  is not the url .. your action seem correct .. so i don't know why don't work ..

Comment: Hi ScaisEdge, I've tried to pass the data to view without the pdf. But it's not generating either. I think this is nothing to do with pdf. The Ajax call and json is not working here. I've updated the question with the present code. Can you have a look?

Comment: Please check in  the browser  console when  you invoke you get ( $.get('index.php?r=stock/sellitem/stockbetweendates',  ) the server return 200 or return others value ..

Comment: Yes. I get  [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 156ms]

Comment: I can not understand what you're doing, you seem to want to make, on the server, the render (that you want to display a view) of _printproductledgerbtdt .. BUT if you want to do this because you're using a Get ajax command that is used to receive data from manage customer .. The render does not send the data (or at least does not send the data in the right way to ajax call) .. if you want to return something (but I do not know what you're trying to return) should prepare it in the format you need and then echo this result so that it is returned to get ajax .. ..

Comment: I've added a screenshot of what I want as output. It's a pdf that is displayed in the browser. I've done it previously with kartik mpdf. Now, In this case among the 3 fields are not attached with any model. I have date column in the database. And I want to find out the stock between 2 dates - startdate and enddate. I'm trying to achieve this through this code. The screenshot I've given - in that case I have a button on the action column which passes the productname as parameter to the controller. In this case I have 2 added field - startdate and enddate. I want to pass 3 of them as parameter.

Comment: then way you don't do this with kartik .. creating a _partialView  with the field you need .. (  and i repeat I can not understand what you're doing)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135257/discussion-between-tanmay-and-scaisedge).